# How to yield all possibilities using efficient nesting in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization, coding-efficiency, forex

Forex Triangular Arb problem:

I'm currently trying to solve an efficient way on how to yield all of the elements of a Dictionary.items(). Let's suppose the array has N length and I need to acquire a all possible combinations where [[A,B],[A,C],[C,B]...]

Currently, it is not efficient due to nesting

```
def Arb(tickers: dict) -> list:
    for first_pair in tickers.items():
        pair1: list = first_pair[0].split("/")

        for second_pair in tickers.items():
            pair2: list = second_pair[0].split("/")


            if pair2[0] == pair1[0] and pair2[1] != pair1[1]:

                for third_pair in tickers.items():
                    pair3: list = third_pair[0].split("/")

                    if pair3[0] == pair2[1] and pair3[1] == pair1[1]:

                      id1 = first_pair[1]["id"]
                      id2 = second_pair[1]["id"]
                      id3 = third_pair[1]["id"]

                      yield [pair1, id1, pair2, id2, pair3, id3]
```

What would be the efficient/pythonic way to return a List with all possible items?

This is an example

```
tickers =   {"EZ/TC": {
              "id": 1
            },
            "LM/TH": {
              "id": 2
            },
            "CD/EH": {
              "id": 3
            },
            "EH/TC": {
              "id":4
            },
            "LM/TC": {
              "id": 5
            },
            "CD/TC":{
              "id": 6
            },
            "BT/TH": {
              "id": 7,
            },
            "BT/TX": {
              "id": 8,
            },
            "TX/TH":{
              "id": 9
            }

            }
```

```
print(list(Arb(tickers)))

[(['CD', 'TC'], 6, ['CD', 'EH'], 3, ['EH', 'TC'], 4), (['BT', 'TH'], 7, ['BT', 'TX'], 8, ['TX', 'TH'], 9)]
```

The Output is a Single List comprised of "lists" of all possibilities.

Comment: What is the input value and expected output ?

Comment: @azro. The input is a Dictionary of N. The output is a single list with all possible combinations.

Comment: Because I tried with something like `value = {"A/B": 5, "B/C": 6, "A/C": 6}` and it returns `[(['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C'])]` which is just the keys in fact, so please give an example

Comment: Edit your post, add 2 examples inputs with their respective expected outputs, without you won't have answers.

Comment: @azro I included an example

Comment: You example is invalid, the '/' is nowhere, as it's not in a string, in fact you awnt to find circular 3 items ? Also this is not a dict, please be coherent

Comment: @azro the "/" is applied when first_pair[0].split("/") is used on the key. I left a comment in the code. Let me know if that clarifies

Comment: No and no. the '/' is not in the string, so you cannot split on it AND this is not a dict byt a list, so you cannot iterate on .items(); seems your method accepts something like `{"A/B": 5, "B/C": 6, "A/C": 6}`

Comment: for first_pair in tickers.items(): will provide a tuple where first_pair[0].split("/") can be used since [0] will contain the symbol. The code is currently providing all possibilities. But the nestings and for loops is taking too many cycles.

Comment: .items() provides  tuples (key,value) from a dictionnary, **AND you don't provide a dict**. Take some time to write a real example input (you cant use https://repl.it/languages/python3 to show us) but if your next comment is wrong again, I'll stop sorry

Comment: @azro. Thanks for the tool, I'll prepare an example right now

Comment: @azro Code updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't to iterate on `items()` as you don't use the values, just the keys. Then you want use `itertools.permutations` to get all the combinations in every order of each pair, then keep the ones that matches letters

```
def verify(v1, v2, v3):
    return v1[0] == v2[0] and v1[1] == v3[1] and v2[1] == v3[0]


def arb(tickers) -> List:
    c = permutations([x.split("/") for x in tickers], r=3)
    return list(filter(lambda x: verify(*x), c))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will read and verify this since it seems more elegant than my nested loops. In the case that I need to Yield some of the values (in addition to the permutations of the keys) from the dictionary, how can the code be adjusted in order to implement that?

Comment: @Corfucinas you need to join the the 2 parts togehher in order to retrieve the value. Seems you may to learn a bit more on python before reaching some complexity in stuff like this

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. I'm currently pursuing that goal, I believe the best way to learn is by taking complex challenges as well. Would it be possible for you to provide me with an example. I'm not entirely certain to know what you mentioned

Comment: @Corfucinas no because your asking  is not clear at all, there's lot of possibilities

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and time. I have updated the original code, now it will include the "id" as well.

Answer (score 0):

Itertools.permutations and itertools.combinations could be helpful for this type of problem: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Here's a link with an example using itertools.permutations:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-itertools-permutations/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have updated the code with an example